# Python keep track of certain attribute counts group by some parent tags

Tags: python, xml, iteration

I need to keep track of the count of certain attributes in a child tag grouped by attribute from parent tag
in the example below

```
  <Unit ...>
    <Unit type="1">
      <Result code1="1" code2="1" />
    <Unit type="2">
      <Result code1="1" code2="1" />
    <Unit type="1">
      <Result code1="444" code2="1" />
    <Unit type="1">
      <Result code1="444" code2="1" />
    <Unit type="2">
      <Result code1="1025" code2="1" />
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

I need to be track sume of all result tags grouped by the value of code1 and code2 : final result something like

code1 counts for Unit Type 1 :  {'1': 1, '444':2}
code1 counts for Unit Type 2 :  {'1':1 , '1025':1}

same for code2 attrib

code2 counts for Unit Type 1 :  {'1': 3}
code1 counts for Unit Type 2 :  {'1':2}

same for the other attribute code2

I used something like

```
for unit in root.iter('Unit'):
    #print(dut.attrib)
    unit_type = int(unit.get('type'))

    code1_map = {}

    
    code1_type_map[siteNumber] = {}

   for result in root.iter('Result'):
        code1 = int(result.get('code1'))
        code2 = int(result.get('code2'))

        if code1 in code1_map:
            code1_map[code1] +=1
        else:
            code1_map[code1] = 1

        code1_type_map[unit_type]= code1_map


#print results:
for key, value in code1_type_map.items():
    print("==>site : value " , key , ' , ' , value)
    for code1, cnt in value.items():
        print(" code1 , count " , code1 , ' , ' , cnt )
```

It seems to always give the total counts, no seperation by the value of attributes code1 and code2

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few issues, so here's a bit of a breakdown:

Problem nr 1:
This code re-initialized the **code1_map** for every **Unit** tag, which implies the results you're seeing are likely not the totals, but instead the **last entry in the list**.

```
for unit in root.iter('Unit'):
    #print(dut.attrib)
    unit_type = int(unit.get('type'))

    code1_map = {}

    code1_type_map[siteNumber] = {}
```

Problem nr 2:
This code is run with a fresh map every time it runs, again referring to my comment above -**this will only get the last result, not the sum of all results.**

Furthermore, you create a **code2** variable here but never use it. I believe your original question stated you wanted both sums, not just the sum of the **code1** result.

```
    for result in root.iter('Result'):
        code1 = int(result.get('code1'))
        code2 = int(result.get('code2'))

        if code1 in code1_map:
            code1_map[code1] +=1
        else:
            code1_map[code1] = 1

        code1_type_map[unit_type]= code1_map
```

Now let's get to the solution;

```
import json

# -- first, we create the variable that will hold our results
code1_results = dict()
code2_results = dict()

# -- second, we start iterating, assuming you're working with 
# -- xml.elementTree.Element here.
for unit_tag in root.iter('Unit'):
    # -- store the unit type in an easily accessible variable
    unit_type = unit_tag.get('type')

    # -- we will keep results per unit type, per code type.
    if unit_type not in results:

        # -- we pre-initialize the dictionary so it's easier to work with
        code1_results[unit_type] = dict()
        code2_results[unit_type] = dict()
    
    # -- iterate here as well in case there are multiple results
    for result_tag in unit_tag.iter('Result'):
        code1 = result_tag.get('code1') or '0'
        code2 = result_tag.get('code2') or '0'

        # -- if this is a new number, make a new counter
        if not code1_results[unit_type].get(code1):
            code1_results[unit_type][code1] = 0

        # -- if this is a new number, make a new counter
        if not code2_results[unit_type].get(code2):
            code2_results[unit_type][code2] = 0

        code1_results[unit_type][code1] += 1
        code2_results[unit_type][code2] += 1

# -- print the results as JSON or however you like
print(json.dumps(code1_results, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
print(json.dumps(code2_results, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below

```
from collections import defaultdict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ''' <Unit>
    <Unit type="1">
      <Result code1="1" code2="1" />
      </Unit> 
    <Unit type="2">
      <Result code1="1" code2="1" />
      </Unit> 
    <Unit type="1">
      <Result code1="444" code2="1" />
     </Unit>  
    <Unit type="1">
      <Result code1="444" code2="1" />
      </Unit> 
    <Unit type="2">
      <Result code1="1025" code2="1" />
     </Unit>
    </Unit>
    '''
data = defaultdict(dict)
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for u in root.findall('.//Unit'):
    r = u.find('Result')
    data[u.attrib['type']][r.attrib['code1']] = r.attrib['code2']
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'1': {'1': '1', '444': '1'}, '2': {'1': '1', '1025': '1'}})
```